# i want to show message once every fields has value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

my html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name" />
    <label for="name">First Name </label>
    <button id="submit" src="images/button.png" width="100" >Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

my script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function() {
      var emptyTextBoxes = $('input[type=text],[type=password]').filter(function() { return this.value == "";
    });
    emptyTextBoxes.each(function() {
        $(emptyTextBoxes).nextAll('label').css({'display':'inline','color':'#F00'});
    });
  });
```

here once  i entered values in the textfield i want to show message(form submitting) how can put that alert message here

Comment: Where would you like to put the message ? why is there no Form tag ? how are you going to submit the form without the form tag ? so many questions ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely re-worked version which puts your input fields into a form and corrects errors in the original javascript...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        // use the id of the form (moved from the button)
        $('#submit').bind('submit',function(){
          // I added `input` in front of your password selector to make it more accureate/efficient
          var emptyTextBoxes = $('input[type=text],input[type=password]').filter(function(){
            return this.value == "";
          });
          // if there are no empty boxes
          if(!emptyTextBoxes.length){
            alert('We finally did it')
          }
          // this prevents the form from being submitted
          return false;
        })
      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- wrap with form and give form id -->
    <form action='#' method='POST' id="submit">
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name" />
      <label for="name">First Name </label>
      <!-- replace button with submit input -->
      <input type='submit' width="100" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The submit button doesn't fire the submit event, the form does.

Comment: That said there is no form, thus no submit event can be fired.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what Billy Moon posted, but with the correct event

```
$('#submit').click(function(event) {

   var emptyTextBoxes = $('input[type=text],[type=password]').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });

   if(emptyTextBoxes.length < 1) {
      alert('Well done, you did it!!');
   } else {
       // ignore the click if all fields haven't been clicked
       event.preventDefault();
   }

});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/beneverard/c9gzY/), original code had a slight error.

Comment: No worries, as mentioned... based on Billy Moon's answer, just tweaked to iron out a few issues.